# what's the object in the method actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)

Tags: java, user-interface, actionlistener

Since it is the method of MoveListener, why the object is GridButton?
If I change it into this.setContentAreaFilled(true), it won't compile because the object is MoveListener.

```
private class GridButton extends JButton {

    public GridButton() {
        setOpaque(false);
        setContentAreaFilled(false);
        setBorderPainted(false);
        addActionListener(new MoveListener());
    }

    private class MoveListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            setContentAreaFilled(true);
        }       
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `MoveListener` inner class is not declared `static`, it inherently carries a reference to the outer class instance that uses it.

Because it has a reference to the outer class, Java's compiler is able to infer what you mean since it's the only accessible method with that name in the current scope. `this` refers to the `MoveListener` in the `actionPerformed` method, however if you did `GridButton.this.setContentAreaFilled(true)` it should work as well since you are explicitly asking for the `GridButton` instance.

The only time you should need to use the `OuterClassName.this.methodName` style is if the outer and inner class share a method with the same name and signature such that it would be ambiguous as to which method needs to be called.

For more information on this topic, read up on [Nested Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html).